# In python socket library document, what does `bufsize[, flags]` mean?

Tags: python, parameters, document, naming

According to Python library [Socket documents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom) function `recvfrom` has parameter `bufsize[, flags]`. In real example that use `recvfrom`, parameters are usally just one number that indicates bufsize. What does `[, flags]` mean?

Comment: From same docs: See the Unix manual page [recv(2)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/recv.2.en.html) for the meaning of the optional argument `flags`; it defaults to zero...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python documentation the notation `[, something]` in a parameter list means that `something` is an optional parameter to the function.

From that socket documentation link:

> See the Unix manual page recv(2) for the meaning of the **optional** argument flags; it defaults to zero.

-- my emphasis on optional.

So if you omit the `flags` argument it will be as though you'd called `recvfrom(bufsize, 0)`